# Python. <Remove Element> in a list

Tags: python-2.7

Title:

> #### [172. Remove Element](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/remove-element/)

[image]
Description:

> Given an array and a value, remove all occurrences of that value in place and return the new length.
>
> The order of elements can be changed, and the elements after the new length don't matter.

My Answer:

> **On LintCode**

```
def removeElement(self, A, elem):
# write your code here
    if A == []:
        return A
    if elem in A:
        sortedA = sorted(A)
        li = []
        for i in xrange(len(sortedA)):
            if sortedA[i] == elem:
                li += [i]
        newLength = sortedA[:min(li)] + sortedA[max(li)+1:]
        return newLength
    else:
        return A
```

> **On my mac**

```
A = [0,4,4,0,0,2,4,4]
elem = 4
def sss(A, elem):   
    if A == []:
        return A
    if elem in A:
        print A
        sortedA = sorted(A)
        print sortedA
        li = []
        for i in xrange(len(sortedA)):
#           print type(i)
            if sortedA[i] == elem:
                li += [i]
                print li
        newLength = sortedA[:min(li)] + sortedA[max(li)+1:]
        print newLength
        return newLength
    else:
        return A
        
print sss(A, elem)
```

This answer **On my mac** work's good, but **On LintCode** doesn't accept.

Comment: I pasted your LintCode snippet into LintCode and "Lint" gave no errors.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Needed to press submit. I know what the issue is. Remove all occurrences of that value _in place_; you are creating a copy of the list by using sorted(). Your solution is too convoluted.

Comment: @Fiskie It says **The order of elements can be changed** so...

Comment: and sorted() builds a completely new list because it doesn't mutate the original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a list comprehension to filter out the unwanted elements?

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, A, elem):
        A[:] = [item for item in A if item != elem]
        return len(A)
```

The key here is the slice notation on the left hand side of the assignment. This makes it an "in place" operation, so the original list `A` is mutated, rather than a copy being made.

**Example usage:**

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 10, 11, 4]
>>> len(l)
10
>>> Solution().removeElement(l, 4)
6
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11]
>>> len(l)
6
```

Comment: This solution is more pythonic than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, yet would like to add the different approaches I tried. Time Complexity is O(n) in all cases.

**Method I: Override the elements if they are not *val* (Logical Approach)**

```
def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
   
    i : int = 0        # This will be an index pointer & will provide the sixe at the end
    
    for j in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[j] != val:       # if the values are not same         
            nums[i] = nums[j]    # Override the value at location i 
            i+=1
            
    return i
```

**Method II: Override the *val* with last array element (Logical Approach)**

```
def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
    i: int = 0
    n: int = len(nums)
    
    while(i<n):
        if(nums[i] == val):
            # Replace the element with last array element & reduce the array size by 1
            nums[i] = nums[n-1]
            n -=1
        else:
            i +=1
        
    return n
```

**Method III  -- Improved form of Method 2  (Python way)**

```
def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
    i : int = 0
    n : int = len(nums)
        
    while i< n :
        print(i, nums, n)
        if val in nums[:n]:
            i = nums.index(val,0,n)
            nums[i] = nums[n-1]
            n -=1
        else:                 
            break
                    
    return n
```

**Method IV  -- Python way**

```
def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
    nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x !=val]
    
    return len(nums)
```

All of them have an average runtime of around 36ms and memory utilization around 13.8MB.